# Using NEST for elasticsearch. How can I search for parents based on children attributes

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to do a simple search, using NEST for customers given specific customer locations.  The POCOS are:

```
class Customer
{
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Identifiers { get; set; }
    public string isIndividual { get; set; }
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public List<CustomerLocation> Locations { get; set; }

class CustomerLocation
{
    public int CustomerLocationId { get; set; }
    public string StreetLine1 { get; set; }
    public string Streetline2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
   
}
```

Currently I am using this search routine - but it fails:

```
                        var searchResponse = _client.Search<Customer>(s => s
                   .Query(q => q
                        .HasChild<CustomerLocation >(hp => hp
                            .Query(qq => qq
                                .Match(m => m
                                    .Field(f => f.City )
                                    .Query(queryText)
                                )
                                
                            )
                         )
                     )
                   .Size(500)
                    );
```

The error message provided is:

> System.Exception
> HResult=0x80131500
> Message=Invalid search. Error is:
> Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful (400) low level call on POST: /customers/_search?typed_keys=true

## Audit trail of this API call:

- [1] SniffOnStartup: Took: 00:00:00.2448689
- [2] SniffSuccess: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.2288784
- [3] PingSuccess: Node: http://127.0.0.1:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0029899
- [4] BadResponse: Node: http://127.0.0.1:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.1639172

## OriginalException: Elasticsearch.Net.ElasticsearchClientException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.. Call: Status code 400 from: POST /customers/_search?typed_keys=true. ServerError: Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: "all shards failed" ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpWebRequestConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData) in C:\Users\russc\source\elasticsearch-net\src\Elasticsearch.Net\Connection\HttpWebRequestConnection.cs:line 63

Any ideas - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between customers and locations is not a parent/child relationship in Elasticsearch terms, which is required in order to use [the `has_child` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-child-query.html).

Unless explicitly mapped, the `Locations` property on `Customer` will be an [`object` type mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html), which would allow you to do

```cs
var queryText = "Sydney";

var searchResponse = client.Search<Customer>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
       .Match(m => m
           .Field(f => f.Locations.First().City)
           .Query(queryText)
       )
    )
    .Size(500)
);
```

*Note*: `f => f.Locations.First().City` is simply an expression to build a path to the JSON field in a strongly typed fashion, by navigating the object graph. It **does not** mean "the first location's city", but evaluates to "any location's city".

This generates the following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "locations.city": {
        "query": "Sydney"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 500
}
```

With the given POCO structure however, it's likely that you'll want to search across multiple location properties. In that case, `Locations` should be explicitly mapped as a [`nested` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

When mapped as a nested data type, the query would be

```cs
var queryText = "Sydney";

var searchResponse = client.Search<Customer>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Nested(n => n
            .Path(p => p.Locations)
            .Query(nq => nq
                .Match(m => m
                    .Field(f => f.Locations.First().City)
                    .Query(queryText)
                )
            )
        )
    )
    .Size(500)
);
```